# Prevent concurrent access of endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, concurrency, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

I have created two API endpoints using Spring Boot.

Ist endpoint: Does some get operation.

IInd endpoint:Overwrites a Mongo DB Collection.

My aim is to prevent concurrent access for multiple users for this second endpoint. And I don't want to block concurrent access to first endpoint.

Both my endpoints are under same controller.

Comment: Use optimistic-locking if in your application there are fewer chances of triggering an update for a shared document by many concurrent threads.... optimistic locks don't block and hence faster but if there  multiple requests for a given document failed due to optimistic locking then retry cost would be there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.